# VBA Paste and on Error display msgbox

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am sorry as this has been probbably discussed many time here. I have got following problem. This macro should paste from clipboard to cells(1,1). And if there is no data in clipboard, I would like it to display msgbox with test "Nothing to paste".

What this keep doing is on error it will enter in cell(1,1) text: "MsgBox "Nothing to paste"" instead of displaying message.

Could you please help me correct mistake? Many thanks in advance!!!

```
Sub Paste()

Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial

If Err Then
MsgBox "Nothing to paste"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `it will enter in cell(1,1) text: "MsgBox "Nothing to paste"" instead of displaying message.` - it's because your last action was copy this line of code and paste it in your sub. And this line is still in clipboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing the clipboard after you paste your text so that the next run wont contain the same text that was just pasted.

```
Sub Paste()
    On Error Resume Next
    Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial

    'Clear clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    If Err Then
        MsgBox "Nothing to paste!"
        Err.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Here is another way that uses the MS clipboard more directly.  First you need to add a reference to: *Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library* in your vba project.

```
Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Sub Paste()
    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = DataObj.GetText

        OpenClipboard (0&)
        EmptyClipboard
        CloseClipboard
        Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Nothing to paste!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to find Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library and it is not on my pc. Also I've tried to search my PC for the FM20.DLL file and no result - this could be because i am using WYSE terminal.

Comment: Is there any other way how to do that? The first one just keep displaying only Error Message and do not paste anything

Comment: I tried the second bit of code there, and simply replaced `activesheet.cells(1,1)` with `selection` but the result was not desirable, the entire clipboard was pasted into each cell in the selection.. I imagine it would be rather drawn out to try to accomplish what automatic pasting does with tables of data. Either way, ty for the info~! (learning new methods is always appreciated!)

Comment: Hi @Reverus - It's a bit limiting in terms of formatting.  If you have only one column but multiple lines that you want split into rows try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33160237/2521004) from John.  It doesn't handle multiple columns however and assumes `vbCr` is what separates your lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Paste()
    On Error Resume Next
    Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial

    'Clear clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    If Err Then
       MsgBox "Nothing to paste!"
       Err.clear
    End If
End Sub
```

now it is working perfectly, I've changed .Paste to .PasteSpecial