# Copy clipboard data to array

Tags: excel, vba

I have to to copy text, from a web page using Ctrl A + Ctrl C, to use in Excel.

The copied text is about 100 lines with different sizes. Let us say one line has a string of 200 characters and the next one has 500 characters and the third maybe 20 characters.

Is there a way to loop over the clipboard data lines and copy them to an array?

Sample of the copied text (made with Ctrl A Ctrl C in the page):
Note : I removed some Lines

---

```
Usernames are XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
DashboardAnalyticsPolicyAdministration
Web Insights
Print View
Start Over
1Select Chart Type
 Logs
Apply Filters
2Choose a Timeframe
Custom: 9/1/2015 12:00:00 AM - 9/30/2015 12:00:00 AM
3Select Filters
Add Filter
2.4 TB
2.0 TB
879.9 GB
656.8 GB
472.0 GB
442.4 GB
242.1 GB
213.5 GB
189.3 GB
103.8 GB
Office 365 - SSL Bypass
Professional Services
Streaming Media
Sites everyone
Internet Services
Corporate Marketing
Miscellaneous
Web Search
News and Media
Social Networking
URL CategoryTop 10TransactionsBytes
```

Comment: You should probably paste the clipboard data to a sheet and then loop the usedrange of the sheet to process the data.

Comment: See this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Clipboard.aspx . Reading from a clipboard into a string variable is easy enough but parsing the resulting string (if pulled from a website) could be hard (though `split` could do a lot of it)

Comment: Is there a way to do that without pasting to a sheet ?

Comment: Why don't you just use a DOM parser to get the text you need instead of copy/pasting?

Comment: or perhaps you can use `IE` automation to do it?

Comment: i can not really use a dom

Comment: @Apocaliptica61 why?

Comment: You should. The `MSXML2` library is a pretty standard include with Windows.

Comment: When I paste your sample data into Notepad I just see one line of text. I think that you are seeing Notepad's word wrap (because it can be sometimes misleading, I don't use word wrap as a default in Notepad). What do you see if you turn off word wrap? If this is the issue, you could always write own basic word-wrap algorithm in VBA to get a long string into an array of shorter strings.

Answer (score 6):

To follow up on my comment, if you follow the instructions from [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Clipboard.aspx) add a reference to `Microsoft Forms Library 2.0` (under `Tools/References` in the VBA editor), the following function takes the contents of the clipboard and splits it into lines:

```
Function ClipToArray() As Variant
    Dim clip As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim lines As String
    clip.GetFromClipboard
    lines = clip.GetText
    lines = Replace(lines, vbCr, "")
    ClipToArray = Split(lines, vbLf)
End Function
```

You can test it like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    A = ClipToArray()
    For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
        Debug.Print A(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Then I went to [this](http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/fire-and-ice) website and copied the poem and then ran `test`. I got the following output in the immediate window:

```
Some say the world will end in fire,
Some say in ice.
From what I've tasted of desire
I hold with those who favor fire.
But if it had to perish twice,
I think I know enough of hate
To say that for destruction ice
Is also great
And would suffice.
```

This worked nicely enough, although you don't have to run many experiments with text copied from the internet before you see that the superficial parsing using `split` leaves much to be desired.

Comment: Is the `Replace` strictly necessary? Seems you could just do `ClipsToArray = Split(lines, vbCrLf)`.

Comment: This is not working for me i need to put it line by line

Comment: @DavidZemens I'm not 100% sure that it is needed, but only Windows text files have two characters at the end of each line. I've downloaded text files made on Unix machines and have had them not display properly in Notepad (since, in effect, Notepad doesn't know how to split them), so thought that `split` might need help in such situations.

Comment: @Apocaliptica61 This is the sort of thing I had in mind in the last sentence of my answer. The problem might be that what you see as lines on a website is browser-supplied word-wrap which might not survive the journey from browser to clipboard. You might need to really examine what string you have in the clipboard and then decide how to split it up. Perhaps you can edit your question by providing a link to the website you are trying to pull data from. (The best solution might be to forget the clipboard and figure out a way to use a tool that can parse HTML.)

Answer (score 2):

I made this for those who want to extract 2D information from a copied range.

```
'Display the content of the clipboard
Sub test()
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    A = ClipToArray()
    For i = LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1)
        tmp = ""
        For j = LBound(A, 2) To UBound(A, 2)
            tmp = tmp & A(i, j) & "  |  "
        Next
        Debug.Print tmp
    Next
End Sub

'Made by LePatay on 2018/12/07
'Extract a 2D array from a copied 2D range
Function ClipToArray()
    'Include Tools -> References -> Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
    'or you will get a "Compile error: user-defined type not defined"
    Dim dataobj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim array2Dfitted As Variant
    Dim cbString As String
    'Special characters
    quote = """"
    tabkey = vbTab
    CarrReturn = vbCr
    LineFeed = vbLf
    'Get the string stored in the clipboard
    dataobj.GetFromClipboard
    On Error GoTo TheEnd
    cbString = dataobj.GetText
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Note: inside a cell, you only find "vbLf";
    'at the end of each row, you find "vbCrLf", which is actually "vbCr & vbLf".
    cbString = Replace(cbString, vbCrLf, CarrReturn)
    'Length of the string
    nbChar = Len(cbString)
    'Get the number of rows
    nbRows = Application.Max(1, nbChar - Len(Replace(cbString, CarrReturn, "")))
    'Get the maximum number of columns possible
    nbColumnsMax = nbChar - Len(Replace(cbString, tabkey, "")) + 1
    'Initialise a 2D array
    Dim array2D As Variant
    ReDim array2D(1 To nbRows, 1 To nbColumnsMax)
    'Initial position in array2D (1st cell)
    curRow = 1
    curColumn = 1
    'Initialise the actual number of columns
    nbColumns = curColumn
    'Initialise the previous character
    prevChar = ""
    'Browse the string
    For i = 1 To nbChar
        'Boolean "copy the character"
        bCopy = True
        'Boolean "reinitialise the previous character"
        bResetPrev = False
        'For each character
        curChar = Mid(cbString, i, 1)
        Select Case curChar
            'If it's a quote
            Case quote:
                'If the previous character is a quote
                If prevChar = quote Then
                    'Indicates that the previous character must be reinitialised
                    '(in case of a succession of quotes)
                    bResetPrev = True
                Else
                    'Indicates the character must not be copied
                    bCopy = False
                End If
            'If it's a tab
            Case tabkey:
                'Indicates the character must not be copied
                bCopy = False
                'Skip to the next column
                curColumn = curColumn + 1
                'Updates the actual number of columns
                nbColumns = Application.Max(curColumn, nbColumns)
            'If it's a carriage return
            Case CarrReturn:
                'Indicates the character must not be copied
                bCopy = False
                'If it's not the 1st character
                If i > 1 Then
                    'Skip to the next row
                    curRow = curRow + 1
                    curColumn = 1
                End If
        End Select
        'If the character must be copied
        If bCopy Then
            'Adds the character to the current cell
            array2D(curRow, curColumn) = array2D(curRow, curColumn) & curChar
        End If
        'If the previous character must be reinitialised
        If bResetPrev Then
            prevChar = ""
        Else
            'Saves the character
            prevChar = curChar
        End If
    Next
    'Create a 2D array with the correct dimensions
    ReDim array2Dfitted(1 To nbRows, 1 To nbColumns)
    'Copies the data from the big array to the fitted one (no useless columns)
    For r = 1 To nbRows
        For c = 1 To nbColumns
            array2Dfitted(r, c) = array2D(r, c)
        Next
    Next
TheEnd:
    ClipToArray = array2Dfitted
End Function
```

Remarks:

- There is no way to tell if cells are merged).
- This code is robust to quotes, successions of quotes, and multiple lines inside a cell.
- It has been tested on a French Excel, Win 7 64 bit. The system of quotes / carriage returns / line feeds may differ on your OS.